# Import typescript file inside javascript file

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, babeljs, create-react-app

I took a react-create-app as a boilerplate for my project.

Then I decided to play with typescript, so I wanted to be able to write TS and JS files at the same time.

I move all necessary files (tsconfig, config-overrides and etc) so my project is built and run well, but there's only one problem: whenever I tried to `import Component from './MyTs.tsx'` inside my routes.js file the Component variable looks like this `/static/media/Component.4c25ef27.tsx` and my app fails because I pass the variable as a routes component.

What am I doing wrong?

config-overrides.js

```js
var paths = require('react-scripts-ts/config/paths')

module.exports = function override(config) {
  config.module.rules.push({
    test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
    include: paths.appSrc,
    loader: require.resolve('babel-loader'),
    options: {
        babelrc: false,
        presets: [require.resolve('babel-preset-react-app')],
        cacheDirectory: true,
    },
  });
  config.module.rules.push({
    test: /\.(ts|tsx)$/,
    include: paths.appSrc,
    loader: ['ts-loader'],
  });

  return config
}
```

---

tsconfig.json

```js
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "build/dist",
    "module": "esnext",
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": ["es6", "dom"],
    "sourceMap": true,
    "allowJs": true,
    "jsx": "react",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "rootDir": "src",
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "noImplicitThis": true,
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "strictNullChecks": true,
    "suppressImplicitAnyIndexErrors": true,
    "noUnusedLocals": true
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "build",
    "scripts",
    "acceptance-tests",
    "webpack",
    "jest",
    "src/setupTests.ts"
  ]
}
```

---

package.json

```js
{
  "name": "src",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "jss": "^6.5.0",
    "jss-camel-case": "^3.0.0",
    "jss-nested": "^3.0.1",
    "jss-px": "^1.0.0",
    "jss-vendor-prefixer": "^4.0.0",
    "react": "^16.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.2.0",
    "react-redux": "^5.0.6",
    "react-router-dom": "^4.2.2",
    "react-scripts": "1.0.17",
    "react-scripts-ts": "^2.12.0",
    "react-virtualized": "^9.16.1",
    "recompose": "^0.26.0",
    "redux": "^3.7.2",
    "redux-act": "^1.5.1",
    "redux-form": "^7.2.0",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.2.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-app-rewired start",
    "build": "react-app-rewired build",
    "test": "react-app-rewired test --env=jsdom",
    "eject": "react-app-rewired eject"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/react": "^16.0.34",
    "babel-eslint": "^8.1.2",
    "eslint": "^4.15.0",
    "eslint-config-airbnb": "^16.1.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.8.0",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "^6.0.3",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.5.1",
    "react-app-rewired": "^1.4.0"
  }
}
```

Comment: Without seeing your specific config, it's hard to tell. Maybe [this blog post](https://mikebridge.github.io/articles/getting-started-typescript-react/) can help.

Comment: @arthurakay I updated the post, please have a look. Thx